# Azure powershell scripts to get the list of user access for all resource and resource groups in one subscription

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

My requirement is something like below,

Resource group, Resource , Access (Read,contributor,owner) , User list

Comment: From Review: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-powershell#list-access?

Comment: I am able to get the Resource group information but not getting in proper format in csv $group=  Get-AzureRmResourceGroup|select-object resourcegroupname 

{
ForEach ( $a IN $group )
{
   Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $a | 
  Select-Object $a.ResourceGroupName,RoleDefinitionName,ObjectType,DisplayName|
  Format-Table -AutoSize|
  Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\LinCh005\RGNew.txt' -Append -Width 300 
        
  }

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, we can use the command `Get-AzRoleAssignment` to get the detailed information of your user https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azroleassignment?view=azps-2.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Resource group access list
$group=  Get-AzureRmResourceGroup|select-object resourcegroupname

{
ForEach ( $a IN $group )
{
   Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $a | 
  Select-Object $a.ResourceGroupName,RoleDefinitionName,ObjectType,DisplayName|
  Format-Table -AutoSize|
  Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\LinCh005\RGNew.txt' -Append -Width 300

}